# Simple GCD program can't run

Tags: c, crash, greatest-common-divisor

Why this program isn't working? This is simple greatest common divisor program using recursive function. It compiles without error, yet when I run program.exe it simply crashes : "The program has stopped working". I've tried it on codeblocks and on Notepad++ . I use gcc compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int gcd(int,int);
int main(int argc,const char* argv[]){
int a;
int b;
a = atoi(argv[1]);
b = atoi(argv[2]);
printf("The greatest common divisor of %d and %d is %d\n",a,b,gcd(a,b));
return 0;
}
int gcd(int a,int b){
    if(a==0)
        return a;
    else
        return gcd(b, a%b);
}
```

Comment: what is the error you getting? pass command line variable when you run the program?

Comment: Are you running the program with valid arguments?

Answer (score 4):

You have this error:

```
  if(a==0)
```

should be

```
  if(b==0)
```

You want to check the divisor is not `0`, not the dividend.

Comment: @ouah: I expected you to know it, I was just pointing it out. The other possibility is that the asker did not pass enough arguments to the program (since there is no check on `argc`).

Comment: No change. After compilation when I press run it says: The program has stopped working

Comment: @MishoMetreveli you have to call your program with the arguments, on Windows that would be (for example): `tst.exe 15 5`

Answer (score 0):

In your program you need to add a check for a>b condition to eliminate divide by 0 problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int gcd(int,int);
int main(int argc, char ** argv[]){
int a;
int b;
int c;
a = atoi(argv[1]);
b = atoi(argv[2]);
if (a<b)
    {                            //swapping if a<b
        c=a;
        a=b;
        b=c;
    }
printf("The greatest common divisor of %d and %d is %d\n",a,b,gcd(a,b));
return 0;
}
int gcd(int a,int b){
    int r1=a%b;
    while(r1>0)
        return gcd(b,r1);
        return b;
}
```